# how to break a string into two parts in java

Tags: java, arrays, string, date

Let's assume a string consists of two parts, day and date.

```
String arr[] = { "Tuesday 8/11/22", "Monday 15/3/21", "Friday 20/5/21" };
```

How can I only print out the latter part (date part) on console?

Answer (score 5):

I recommend you use the date-time API instead of performing string manipulation of the elements. The string manipulation will not give you all the benefits that you can get by the specialized date-time API.

### Bonus

You get your dates validated free of cost e.g. one of your dates, `Friday 20/5/21` is incorrect. This date was Thursday and the `java.time` API can perform this check for you automatically.

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String arr[] = { "Tuesday 8/11/22", "Monday 15/3/21", "Friday 20/5/21" };
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE d/M/uu", Locale.ENGLISH);
        for (String s : arr) {
            LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(s, parser);

            // Now you can get individual units from date in a variety of ways
            System.out.println(date.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.ENGLISH));
            System.out.println(date.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.ENGLISH));
            System.out.println(date.getYear());

            // You can also format it in the desired ways
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/M/uu", Locale.ENGLISH);
            String formatted = date.format(formatter);
            System.out.println(formatted);
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
Tuesday
Tue
2022
8/11/22
Monday
Mon
2021
15/3/21
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Friday 20/5/21' could not be parsed: Conflict found: Field DayOfWeek 4 differs from DayOfWeek 5 derived from 2021-05-20
        at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:2023)
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the day and date will stay in that format you can use the `split()` function:

```
class DateSplit {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "Tuesday 8/11/22";
        String[] result = a.split(" ");
        System.out.println(result[1]);
    }
}
```

where the delimiter splitting the string is the whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(String str : arr) {
  System.out.println(str.split(" ")[1])
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to give a brief explanation of how this works / how it solves the problem, and how it's different than existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                String arr[] = { "Tuesday 8/11/22", "Monday 15/3/21", "Friday 20/5/21" };
            
            for(int count = 0; count < arr.length; count++) {
                String[] s = arr[count].split(" ");
                System.out.println(s[1]);
            }
        }
    }
```